# Setting a static route in CentOS

Tags: networking, routing, centos6.2

Here is my `route -n` output:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
```

And if I try to add a static route by this command:

`route add -net 192.168.50.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.50.1`

I get the following output:

`SIOCADDRT: No such process`

Why that? Can anybody explain my the concept of adding static routes in linux.

If I also have a `route-eth0` file under the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/` directory, with this line in it: `123.123.123.0/24 via 123.123.124.1`, no effect is achieved after I restart the network.

So, can anybody give me some explanations, links or related stuff to read on this?

Thanks!

---

NOTE:
What I observed: if I have added the `192.168.50.0` network and points to 'default' gateway (0.0.0.0), my command works good. But if I haven't it, I got the already mentioned ERROR. So, can you show me what I need to do more and where I'm wrong?

P.S. I'm a kind of a newbie in linux networking.

Comment: Are your IP's in network-scripts valid ?

Comment: there is probably something wrongly configured in your networking. post your /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 and /etc/sysconfig/network files

Comment: @thanosk I don't have a /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 file. And my network file looks like:`NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=artaxerxe`. So, if I need more on this, just suggest me what I need to do. Thanks.

Comment: What do you have under? Also, can you run the following and paste it into your paste: "ip addr"

Comment: @artaxerxe well it seems you have no networking configured at all. Run a tool like system-config-network to help you through

Comment: The posted output seems to be taken from 'route -n' not from 'ifconfig'.

Comment: @Khaled Thanks. It was my mistake. I corrected it.

Comment: @artaxerxe: Can you please post the output of `ip addr show` and `ifconfig`?

Comment: @Khaled Now I'm not at my working station. I'll do it on Monday. Until then, I cannot do anything. I beg your pardon...:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The route you're trying to add is recursive.

```
route add -net 192.168.50.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.50.1
```

This translate to the following:

> The next hop for 192.168.50.0/24 is 192.168.50.1
>
> *Ok. What is the next hop for 192.168.50.1?*
>
> The next hop for 192.168.50.0/24 is 192.168.50.1
>
> *> Uh? But this ain't possible.* Then outputs the cryptic `SIOCADDRT: No
>   such process`

This is confirmed by the second route you added:

```
route add -net 192.168.50.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.122.x
```

Your default gateway should be in the 192.168.122.0/24 network to be reachable from your computer.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the "SIOCADDRT: No such process" error if "You attempted to set a route for a network before setting a host route for the gateway which handles traffic for that network."

ANSWER: First create a host route, then create a net route.

e.g. for network in question: local -> 192.168.50.1 -> 192.168.50.xx

```
route add -host 192.168.50.1 dev eth0
route add -net 192.168.50.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.50.1
```

This helped me https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.TECH142841.html